# C++ Include path on x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ with OpenGL

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, g++, mingw32

I am trying to get an OpenGL program working on both `linux` and `windows`.
Here's my code [file=main.cc]:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include "GL/glew.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout << "Hello World\n";    
    return 0;
}
```

Simple enough. I'm on Linux and using
`g++ main.cc -lGL -lGLEW -lSDL2`
to compile my program. It works perfectly fine and if I run `./a.out` I get a Hello World on my screen.
Then I try to compile it on `Linux` for `Windows` using the command
`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cc -lGL -LGLEW -LSDL2`
Then however i get the error:

```
main.cc:3:21: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include "GL/glew.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

I've already tried adding the `-I/inclulde/path` option with paths like `/usr/include` `/usr/include/GL` `usr/include` and the like, yet nothing wants to compile.
The Libraries that I'm using (or planning to) were installed using
`#apt install libgl-dev libglew-dev libsdl2-dev`
Any help would be very much appreciated (although I feel this is an incredibly easy fix that I'm just too stupid to figure out on my own)

Comment: Did you already search on your system where the `GL` directory is exactly located?

Comment: You would need to use `#include <GL/glew.h>` (angle brackets, not quotes) for the compiler to search your system's include path, otherwise it's going to look relative to the source file that includes it -- so your `-I` options won't do any good when using double quotes. FYI, I do cross-compile OpenGL programs for Windows on Linux using x86_64-w64-mingw32 on Debian, and there is no distro-provided `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/GL/glew.h`. You can try using the one from `libglew-dev` though I don't know if it will work for a build targeting Windows. I simply don't use GLEW in my programs.

Comment: the file is located at `/usr/include/GL/glew.h`;  but I still couldn't get it to work using angled brackets.

Comment: @GodlikeBlock Because the cross-compiler only looks in `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include`. If you are using angled brackets, `-I/usr/include` should work. Make sure `-I` appears before your source files on the command line.

Comment: @cdhowie Then that gives me even more errors and now it's complaining that it cannot find `#include <gnu/stubs.h>`, and trying to include that as well in the search space only yields more error messages about `conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uintptr_t' 'typedef unsigned long int uintptr_t'`

Comment: That basically means that it found the file, but it looks like it's not compatible with Windows. You may need to install the Windows glew sdk on Linux.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll give that a try and see how far I get